# Как сделать автодополнение кавычек в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

Автодополнение скобок в настройках Visua Studio есть, а кавычек не увидел, подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под скобками подразумевается всё автодополнение. К сожалению не знаю с каким именно языком работаете именно Вы, но в принципе решение одно и то же.

**Если Visual Studio на английском языке:**

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General > Automatic brace completion
```

**Если Visual Studio на русском языке:**

```
Отладка > Параметры... > Текстовый редактор > Все языки > Общие > Автозавершение скобок
```

P.S И логично, если хотите применить данные настройки не для всех языков, а для одного или нескольких конкретно, то уже надо в разделе каждого ЯП делать всё то же самое.